# Удаление строк по заданному фильтру в Excel или Word

Tags: excel, ms-word

Имеется огромная таблица в формате doc и xls. Данных порядка 1000 страниц в ворде. 
Таблица имеет такой вид:

2-2/2013   | текст | |
2-132/2013 | текст | |

и есть список первого столбца. Например 2-2, 2-13 через запятую (далее фильтр) и.т.д. Нужно удалить из таблицы строки, первый столбец, который совпадает с фильтром.

Обрабатывать таблицу не важно где, в word или xls. Подскажите в какую сторону копать?  из ЯП знаю php, если возможно на нём, то ткните носом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Преобразовать список на удаление в "один номер на строку" - Word, Поиск и Замена, заменить запятые на символ "знак абзаца".
2. Загрузить таблицу из Word в Excel на Лист1.
3. Загрузить фильтр из Word в Excel на Лист2.
4. На листе Лист1 в ячейке, скажем, H1, ввести формулу `=ЛЕВСИМВ(A1;НАЙТИ("/";A1)-1)`.
5. В ячейке I1 ввести формулу `=ВПР(H1;Лист2!A:A;1;ЛОЖЬ)`.
6. Выделить ячейки H1:I1 и растянуть на всю высоту данных.
7. Выделить все столбцы данных и выполнить сортировку по столбцу I.
8. Удалить все строки, где у столбца I значение НЕ равно `#Н/Д`.
9. Удалить столбцы H и I.

Answer (score 1):

В книге *Excel* на листе *Лист1* расположена таблица. В строке 1 - шапка таблицы. В столбце *А* - коды, которые нужно сравнивать с фильтром. В ячейке *I1* - коды через запятую (данные для фильтра).

Макрос разместить в общем модуле. 
После отработки кода будут удалены строки, у которых коды столбца *А* найдены в строке из * I1*

```
Sub DelRow()
Dim aData()
Dim rRng As Range
Dim sFilter As String
Dim i As Long, n As Long
    With Worksheets("Лист1")
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row: If i < 2 Then Exit Sub
        aData = .Range("A1:A" & i).Value
        sFilter = .Range("I1").Value

        For i = 2 To UBound(aData)
            If InStr(sFilter, Trim$(Split(aData(i, 1), "/")(0))) Then
                n = n + 1

                If rRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rRng = .Cells(i, 1)
                Else
                    Set rRng = Union(rRng, .Cells(i, 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not rRng Is Nothing Then rRng.EntireRow.Delete: Set rRng = Nothing
    MsgBox "Удалено строк: " & n, 64, ""
End Sub
```

Строку поиска лучше дополнить, иначе возможно определение части значения из фильтра:

```
If InStr("," & sFilter & ",", "," & Trim$(Split(aData(i, 1), "/")(0)) & ",") Then
```